# How to forward a message from telegram channel to user using bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

I am using python telethon module. I want to send some messages having media files from a public telegram channel to a user using bot. I get the required message by `GetMessagesRequest` function by logging in as a telegram client i.e. not as bot and channel info using `get_entity`as bot.

```
channelInfo=await BOT.get_entity(tl.types.PeerChannel(channelId))
MSG = await CLIENT(functions.channels.GetMessagesRequest( channel=channelInfo.username, id=[MessageId]))
Forward_MSG = MSG.messages[0]
```

Using `await BOT.send_message(USER, MSG)` or `await BOT.send_file(USER, MSG)` gives `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MediaEmptyError: The provided media object is invalid (caused by SendMediaRequest)`

Using `await BOT.forward_messages(USER, MSG)` gives `TypeError: Cannot cast NoneType to any kind of Peer.`

How can I send `Forward_MSG` to a user as a bot ?

Comment: What is the type of `Forward_MSG` ?  Output of `print(type(Forward_MSG))`

Comment: If you are sure that `USER` is NOT `None`, try to specify the 3rd parameter `from_peer` of `forward_messages` manually. If that still does not work, please clarify the version of Telethon.